# Windows System Message Process Name

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, task-manager

What does the task manager list as system messages? For example, if you do a shutdown /r /t 600 /c Message , what would the PID/name of the system message be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your event viewer and filter your system logs by event ID's 1074, 6006, 6008. [See this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78335-read-shutdown-logs-event-viewer-windows.html).

Comment: Is Event ID the same as PID? I dont think it is.

Comment: I was more looking for something that I could use to cancel the message from appearing.